# Check if two lines start with the same character, if so the output average, if not, print actual value

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'd like to check if two rows start with the same number in the 1st column, if that happens, then the average of the 2nd column should be displayed. File example:

```
01  21    6    10%       93.3333%
01  22    50   83.3333%  93.3333%
02  20.5  23   18.1102%  96.8504%
02  21.5  100  78.7402%  96.8504%
03  22.2  0    0%        100%
03  21.2  29   100%      100%
04  22.5  1    5.55556%  100%
04  23.5  17   94.4444%  100%
05  22.7  9    7.82609%  100%
05  21.7  106  92.1739%  100%
06  23    11   17.4603%  96.8254%
06  22    50   79.3651%  96.8254%
07  20.5  14   18.6667%  96%
07  21.5  58   77.3333%  96%
08  21.8  4    100%      100%
09  22.6  0    0%        100%
09  21.6  22   100%      100%
```

For instance, the two first lines start with `01`, but there is only one line starting with `08` (15th line). Therefore, the output based on these two cases should be:

```
01 21.5
...
...
...
08 21.8
...
...
...
```

I ended up with the following awk line, which works great when the file always has two similar lines, but it fails using the file shown above (because the 15th line):

```
awk '{sum+=$2} (NR%2)==0{print sum/2; sum=0;}'
```

Any hint is welcomed,

Comment: So, am I understanding correctly that you want to average together all adjacent lines that have the same first column? (The average of one number is of course that number—so this includes spitting out rows without a pair unchanged). Also, does it have to be awk?

Comment: Also asked on http://stackoverflow.com/q/32789740/7552 -- there be answers there. @gery, one site at a time please.

Comment: @glennjackman sorry for that Glenn, I will delete this one.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
function reset(){
    n = $1; sum = $2; cnt = 1
}
{
    reset()
    while(getline){
        if(n == $1){
            sum += $2; cnt++;
        }else{
            print n, sum/cnt
            reset()
        }
    }
}
END{ print n, sum/cnt }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you please post it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789740/check-if-two-lines-start-with-the-same-character-if-so-the-output-average-if-n, because I will delete this post.